# Set URL to hyperlink with Rest call in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios, react-hooks

I have to download some files using the hyperlink. The value of the URL will be received from the server when the download link is clicked.

```
const [downloadEpi,setDownloadEpi] = useState({link:'',name:''});


const premiumDownload=(email,epiId,quality)=>{

        const download ={
            email: email,
            episodeId: epiId,
            quality: quality
         };
 

        axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:9094/api/tv-series/premiumDownload`,download,{
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }).then(res=>{
            const downloadRes = res.data;
            setDownloadEpi({link:downloadRes.downloadLink,name:downloadRes.epiName});
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log(error);
        });
    }


    <DownloadButton  premium onClick={()=>premiumDownload('benz@gmail.com','viki_s01_e01','480p')}>
              <a href={downloadEpi.link && downloadEpi.link} download={downloadEpi.name && downloadEpi.name} className="link">download with IDM</a>
      </DownloadButton>
```

when I click the download button the link will be called with an empty string before the actual value render. So I have to click the button two times to download.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a link from the server, it takes time so `href` contains the default value.

you should hide the button until you get the link or show the loading state

```
<DownloadButton  premium onClick={()=>premiumDownload('benz@gmail.com','viki_s01_e01','480p')}>
    <a href={downloadEpi.link && downloadEpi.link} download={downloadEpi.name && downloadEpi.name} className="link">{downloadEpi.link ? "download with IDM" : "Loading..."}</a>
</DownloadButton>
```

Comment: thank you. It didn't work but I got an idea from your answer.

Comment: basically, I was also just trying to give you an idea for adding a loading state

Answer (score 0):

You should trigger link click manually from `premiumDownload` function. Currently first click populates `a` html element with data for `href` and `download` attributes. If you need to do stuff in one click just create `ref` to `a` tag and use it to assign data to `href` and `download` attributes and also trigger `click` event:

```
const aRef = React.useRef()

const premiumDownload = (email,epiId,quality) => {
    const download ={
        email: email,
        episodeId: epiId,
        quality: quality
     };

    axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:9094/api/tv-series/premiumDownload`, download, {
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    }).then(res=>{
        const downloadRes = res.data;
        
         if (aRef.current) {
             aRef.current.href = downloadRes.downloadLink
             aRef.current.download = downloadRes.epiName
             
             aRef.current.click()
         }
    }).catch(error=>{
        console.log(error);
    });
}

<DownloadButton  premium onClick= 
{()=>premiumDownload('benz@gmail.com','viki_s01_e01','480p')}>
          <a href={downloadEpi.link && downloadEpi.link} download= 
{downloadEpi.name && downloadEpi.name} className="link">download with 
IDM</a>
  </DownloadButton>
```

Have not tested it but should work (▀̿Ĺ̯▀̿ ̿)

Comment: I have tested. both work concurrently. I mean empty URL will be call and download start by browser and at the same time IDM download box will appear to download

Answer (score 0):

I phased the same issue in my current project and I solved it like this.
I hope it will also work for you

```js
const premiumDownload=(email,epiId,quality)=>{

        const download ={
            email: email,
            episodeId: epiId,
            quality: quality
         };
 

        axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:9094/api/tv-series/premiumDownload`,download,{
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }).then(res=>{
            const downloadRes = res.data;
            
            // for downloading file automatically
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = `${downloadRes.downloadLink}`;
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log(error);
        });
    }


    <DownloadButton  premium onClick={()=>premiumDownload('benz@gmail.com','viki_s01_e01','480p')}>
             download with IDM
      </DownloadButton>
```

Comment: I did it but cross-origin blocked will arise. It works with some servers and some server gives cross-origin policy block

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it in one way and it will affect performance but works fine

1. disabling premium download function and passing request values via props.
2. call the endpoint in the componentDidMount

   ```
    useEffect(()=>{

        const download ={
            email: props.email,
            episodeId: props.epiId,
            quality: props.quality
         };

         axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:9094/api/tv-series/premiumDownload`,download,{
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }).then(res=>{
            const downloadRes = res.data;
            setDownloadEpi({link:downloadRes.downloadLink,name:downloadRes.epiName});
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log(error);
        });

       },[]);
   ```

   {downloadEpi.link ? "download with IDM" : "Loading..."}